# AngularJS, $cookies inside a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive, in which I'd like to use $cookies, to check whether a page has been visited or not.  The code for my directive is:

```
angular.module('waApp').directive('waNewToGamma', function(
 $cookies
 ){ 'use strict';

    return {
        templateUrl: '/components/right-sidebar/new-to-gamma/new-to-gamma.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
    },
        link: function(scope, elements, attrs){
            var visited = false;

            if ($cookies.get("ResultsPageVisits") > 1 ) {
                visited = true;
            }
            console.log('visited is');
            console.log(visited);
        }

    };
});
```

I get an error, 
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
with regards to the line 
    if ($cookies.get("ResultsPageVisits") > 1 )
about $cookies.get.

I know that ngCookies needs to be injected into the app; this is done in elsewhere in the definition of the application.  I'm fairly certainly that I've correctly injected $cookies into this directive, and this cookie does exist in the browser.  So where have I gone wrong?  Have I, in fact, injected $cookies incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using an older version of Angular, in which $cookies.get() isn't a method, and instead you use $cookies.key directly!